Add scroll event to MUI Autocomplete component
I am building a grafana plugin using React. In order to create a component I have implemented the MUI Autocomplete component. I want to be able to add an event listener to listen to scroll events so that when a user reaches the bottom of a initial partial list I can lazy load more entries for them to scroll through.
Here is how I am utilizing the component currently.
<Autocomplete
          freeSolo
          options={columnOptions}
          onChange={handleTagChange}
          multiple
          disableCloseOnSelect
          isOptionEqualToValue={(option, value) => isEqual(option, value)}
          value={filterTags}
          inputValue={textInput}
          filterOptions={filterOptions}
          onInputChange={handleTextChanged}
          getOptionLabel={(option) => {
            
            if (typeof option === 'string') {
              return option;
            }
            return option.value;
          }}
          renderTags={(value: readonly FilterTag[], getTagProps) =>
            value.map((option: FilterTag, index: number) => (
              // eslint-disable-next-line react/jsx-key
              <Chip
                color={getTagColor(option.mode)}
                label={option.value}
                {...getTagProps({ index })}
              />
            ))
          }
          renderInput={(params) => {
            return (
              <TextField {...params} {...restOfProps} placeholder="Filter" />
            );
          }}
        />

I have tried wrapping the Autocomplete in a div and adding the event there, adding a event directly to the Autocomplete, and using DOM query selector to try and add the event to a nested list of the Autocomplete component. Unfortunately I have haven't been able to correctly capture the event.
Thank you for any help with this.
